# FragmentManager is already executing transactions. When is it safe to initialise pager after commit?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have an activity hosting two fragments. The activity starts off showing a loader while it loads an object. The loaded object is then passed to both fragments as arguments via newInstance methods and those fragments are attached.

```
final FragmentTransaction trans = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
trans.replace(R.id.container1, Fragment1.newInstance(loadedObject));
trans.replace(R.id.container2, Fragment2.newInstance(loadedObject));
trans.commit();
```

The second fragment contains a android.support.v4.view.ViewPager and tabs. onResume we initialise it like follows

```
viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(adapter.getCount()); //the count is always < 4
tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
```

The problem is android then throws

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing
>   transactions

With this stack trace: *(I took `android.support` out of the package names just for brevity)*

> v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1620)
>                                                                                          at
>   v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:637)
>                                                                                          at
>   v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:143)
>                                                                                          at v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1235)
>                                                                                          at v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1083)
>                                                                                          at
>   v4.view.ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(ViewPager.java:847)

The data shows if `setOffscreenPageLimit(...);` is removed. Is there another way to avoid this issue?

When in the lifecycle is the fragment transaction complete so that I can wait to setup my pager?

Comment: apparently, the android `ViewPager` will promote a `NullPointerException` inside `onCreateView` of the fragment inside the pager to a `IllegalStateException : FragmentManager is already executing transactions` ... just in case someone drops by and needs to know

Answer (score 264, accepted):

Simply use `childFragmentManger()` for `viewpager` inside a `Fragment`

```
mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
```

Comment: Dude! You saved my day!! :D Thanks a ton! I was using Nested fragments and your "getChildFragmentManager" trick worked like charm! ^_^

Comment: This worked in the case where going 'back' (via back button) to the activity/fragment combo was crashing as well.  Good call.

Comment: Thanks!! My app crashed when i used Apply Changes and Restart Activity as run button.

Comment: This is right solution if you are using nested fragments and reusing the same fragment manager.

Answer (score 89):

I had this exception when quickly replacing 2 fragments AND using `executePendingTransactions()`. Without calling this there was no exception.

What was my case?
I open a fragment A and in its `onResume()` (under a condition) I ask the activity to replace the fragment with fragment B. At that point the exception occurs.

My solution was to use a `Handler.post(runnable)` which places the query on the end of the thread queue instead of running it immediately. This way we ensure that the new transaction will be executed after any previous transactions are completed.

So my solution was as simple as:

```
Handler uiHandler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
uiHandler.post(new Runnable()
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        openFragmentB(position);
    }
});
```

Comment: Simple and effective. I have used postDelayed though. In my use case it was even better, since a lot of stuff is going on on initialisation phase

Comment: This worked, but I wonder how does this fix the issue internally?

Comment: @David It will post a task to the main thread's queue rather than trying to open the fragment forcefully. So the queue will process fragment commits one by one.

Comment: Thanks for the effective solution, `Handler()` is deprecated, instead you can use `Handler(Looper.getMainLooper())`

Comment: You are correct, I updated the answer.

Comment: very correct and easy, I actually used post Delayed just to be double sure

Answer (score 28):

If you're targeting sdk 24 and above you can use:

```
FragmentTransaction.commitNow()
```

instead of `commit()`

If you're targeting older versions, try calling:

```
FragmentManager.executePendingTransactions()
```

after the call to `commit()`

Comment: FragmentManager.executePendingTransactions() will also cause the exception, as inside its code there is a call to execPendingActions() --> ensureExecReady(true) -->  if (mExecutingActions) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("FragmentManager is already executing transactions");
        }

Comment: This not work for me. The two methods show the crash: java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing transactions

Comment: commitNow along with addToBackStack usage also failed :(

Comment: Anyone using this should know that it's a blocking method, running it in the UI thread will make your app freeze while transitioning. M.Paunov's and Hitesh Sahu's answers are reliable for a production ready app.

Answer (score 13):

I Had a similar issue,

A mainAcitivity adding fragmentA.

Then fragmentA callback mainactivity to replace itself with fragmentB.

MainActivity throw exception **fragmentmanager already executing transaction** when replace and commit transaction with fragmentB.

The issue actually comes from fragmentB.

I have a TabHost in fragment B which require `getfragmentmanager()` to add tabfragment.

Replace `getfragmentmanager()`  by `getchildfragmentmanager()` in fragmentB solve the issue.

Answer (score 11):

I had same problem. However, I was using the `FragmentStateAdapter` constructor that gets only the `FragmentActivity`:

```
package androidx.viewpager2.adapter;

public FragmentStateAdapter(
    @NonNull FragmentActivity fragmentActivity
) {
    this(fragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragmentActivity.getLifecycle());
}
```

Even though it gets the Lifecycle from `fragmentActivity` instance, it was not working at all.

Then, diving into the code of the `FragmentStateAdapter`, I saw there is another constructor where you can pass the Lifecycle instance.

```
package androidx.viewpager2.adapter;

public FragmentStateAdapter(
    @NonNull FragmentManager fragmentManager,
    @NonNull Lifecycle lifecycle
) {
    mFragmentManager = fragmentManager;
    mLifecycle = lifecycle;
    super.setHasStableIds(true);
}
```

So, I changed my `PageAdapter` constructor to receive the `FragmentManager` as `childFragmentManager` and the LifeCycle from the `viewLifecycleOwner`. And pass those parameters to the `FragmentStateAdapter` constructor:

```
class MyPagerAdapter(
    fragmentManager: FragmentManager,
    lifecycle: Lifecycle
) : FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentManager, lifecycle) {
  //...
}
```

Then, when calling my PagerAdapter constructor, I pass the FragmentManager and
I get the lifeCycle from the `viewLifecycleOwner`:

```
val myPagerAdapter = MyPagerAdapter(
    fragmentManager = childFragmentManager,
    lifecycle = viewLifecycleOwner.lifecycle
)
```

**[UPDATE]**
MyPagerAdapter is set from a Fragment.

Comment: Had exact same issue (around same time). Would have never figured reading other answers. 
Thank you :)

Comment: viewLifecycleOwner not found in Ativity. Any idea

Comment: @PankajKumar When calling viewLifecycleOwner basically you are calling the getViewLifecycleOwner() method from the androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.  
In this case (I am not sure - but worth to try) You could try to call supportFragmentManager | getSupportFragmentManager() to get the FragmentManager ans just call lifecycle | getLifecycle() from the activity.

Comment: `public FragmentStateAdapter(@NonNull Fragment fragment)`

I use this constructor solved my problem

Answer (score 5):

### ViewPager2

It is quite an old answer from the time of `ViewPager` and has helped many to solve the issue who came across this. Just in case you are having `ViewPager2` and face similar issue then,

We know this happens when we have `ViewPager2` inside a fragment and `FragmentStateAdapter` class has a constructor with `Fragment` parameter, so you can use that to create your adapter.

Like,

```
class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(fragment: Fragment): FragmentStateAdapter(fragment)
```

Then,

```
val pagerAdapter = ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(this)
```

Answer (score 3):

Got a similar error not connected to question but hops its helps someone when working with firebase.
Remove `activity`, `requireActivity` or this from `.addSnapshotListener()`, keep it blank.

```
 videosListener = videosCollectionRef
            .addSnapshotListener() { snapshot, exception ->

                if (exception != null) {
                    Log.e("Exception", "Could not retrieve documents: $exception")
                }

                if (snapshot != null) {
                    parseData(snapshot)
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thanks this was helpful, but now I can open the fragment only once if I got back to it, it crashes.

Comment: @AbhishekAN I would need to see more of your code to help you out more. Hope you solve your problem mate.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is using Robolectric >3.6 and at least through 4.0.2 with a ViewPager you may see this even with correct code.

There is related information in [this github issue](https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/issues/3698#issuecomment-441839491) tracking the problem for Robolectric.

The issue is not resolved as I write this answer, and the only workarounds known are to use @Config(sdk={27}) which appears to work for some but did not work for me, or implement a ViewPagerShadow with a workaround in your test package with the rather-long code referenced on github (I can include it here if that is better but this may not be relevant enough as an answer?) and use @Config(shadows={ShadowViewPager.class})

Answer (score 1):

I used/extended my adapter with `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` instead of `FragmentPagerAdapter` this resolved my issue.

Use `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`if the fragments are dynamic and are changing frequently during run-time.

Use `FragmentPagerAdapter` if the fragments are static and do NOT change frequently during run-time.

enlightened from this article, 
https://medium.com/inloopx/adventures-with-fragmentstatepageradapter-4f56a643f8e0

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Navigation from one fragment to another by add method. The problem was that I added fragment transition in the `onViewCreadted` method. Then I tried to move the transition in `onResume` method. That also does not help. So I added transition half-second after the resume. After that everything was fine.

It was a small crush that affected less than half percent of my users. Even though, it was very annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Just do not call
`FragmentTransaction#commit()` from fragment which is already been in the same  `FragmentManager` at another transaction process

For ex:

Activity:

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
     val fragment = MyFragment()
     setFragment(fragment)
    }


    fun setFragment(fragment: Fragment){
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(...,fragment, ...)
            .commit()    
     }
```

MyFragment:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
/*
*  here error will occurs, because the fragment MyFragment is in current transaction
*/
activity?.setFragment(AnotherFragment())//error
}
```

**Solution:**

Do this:

Activity:

```
 override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    
     setFragment(MyFragment())
    ...
    setFragment(AnotherFragment())
    }


    fun setFragment(fragment: Fragment){
        supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
            .replace(...,fragment, ...)
            .commit()    
     }
```