# What is causing java.lang.IllegalArgumentException in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin

This error is randomly thrown at any time and its logged on google play console. I'm unable to figure out what's the cause.

[image]

Comment: Clean-rebuild and try

Comment: Delete bin and obj folders also.

Comment: I've rebuild it dozens of times and application is working fine but this error occurs randomly and causing application crash, I've also delete bin and obj folder couple of times

Answer (score 0):

[image]

I think this is the answer to the problem that you have, see the full discussion here:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-client/issues/348

If you have already try this solution and it did not work, try to see this discussion:

[FragmentManager is already executing transactions after using method setOffscreenPageLimit()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40094023/fragmentmanager-is-already-executing-transactions-after-using-method-setoffscree)