# Android 'FragmentManager is already executing transactions' when notifydatasetchanged runs on ui thread

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager

I'm using a **TabLayout** with **ViewPager**. I have **two tabs** in my tab layout which both have a **different instances** of the **same fragment object.** Both fragments have the same recycler view layout as well.

Problem: When I load the entire activity after getting the server objects back, I'm trying to populate both tab views with the new object, but I get the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing 
transactions
```

. So in my main activity:

```
public class MyMainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
    private TabLayout tabLayout;
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private MyAdapter adapter;
    private MyFragment fragmentA;
    private MyFragment fragmentB;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.my_activity);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    viewPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
    adapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), new 
ArrayList<>(), new ArrayList<>());

    // Instantiate the fragments here
    adapter.addFragment(....A, "Title A");
    adapter.addFragment(....B, "Title B");
    .....
    .....
    .....
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    public void refreshPage() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // This line crashes
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I tried using getChildFragmentManager but I can't because you need to call that via a fragment object. **I cannot show much code as most of it is proprietary and I had to make the code as generic as possible.**

When I comment out the line that crashes, my recycler view for the first tab does not refresh **unless I scroll.** while the second tab **does not refresh at all.** Did anyone have the same issue before? How did you resolve it?

**P.S I'm not using any FragmentManager or transactions so I'm not sure why it gives me that exception.**

Comment: May already be addressed in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38722325/fragmentmanager-is-already-executing-transactions-when-is-it-safe-to-initialise

Comment: @TylerV Yes I tried most of the suggestions there, and other questions similar, which is why I asked my own now.

Comment: And as I mentioned, childFragmentManager() requires a Fragment instance to be attached first to the activity...

Comment: Provide more of the stack trace.