# FragmentManager is already executing transactions. A callback in MainActivity to create two Fragments hosted by FragmentPagerAdapter

Tags: android

I've got an activity hosting one top fragment with a RecyclerView and two bottom fragments being managed by the ViewPagerAdapter. Once the RecyclerView has received all items from the local database, it uses a callback to inform the MainActivity to prepare two other fragments that should use data from the list of items from the top fragment.

```
@Override
public void onModulesRetrieved(List<Module> moduleList) {
    Log.d(TAG, "onModulesRetrieved in MainActivity");
    ViewPagerAdapter vpa = new ViewPagerAdapter(
            this,
            moduleList,
            getSupportFragmentManager());


    viewPager.setAdapter(vpa);

    TabLayout tl = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    tl.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
}
```

The ViewPagerAdapter accepts the list and returns the fragment depending on the tab position:

```
class ViewPagerAdapter(
    private val mContext: Context,
    private val moduleList: List<Module>,
    fragMgr: FragmentManager) : FragmentPagerAdapter(fragMgr) {



// determines the fragment for each tab
override fun getItem(position: Int): Fragment {
    return when (position) {
        0 -> CalcFragmentBottomA.newInstance(moduleList as ArrayList<Module>)
        else -> CalcFragmentBottomB(moduleList as ArrayList<Module>)
    }
}

// This determines the number of tabs
override fun getCount(): Int {
    return 2
}

// This determines the title for each tab
override fun getPageTitle(position: Int): CharSequence? {
    // Generate title based on item position
    return when (position) {
        0 -> mContext.getString(R.string.bottom_tab_a)
        1 -> mContext.getString(R.string.bottom_tab_b)
        else -> null
    }
}
```

}

If I go to a different activity hosting different fragment and back to mainActivity, an exception starts from dispatchStateChange method in the FragmentManager:

```
private void dispatchStateChange(int nextState) {
    try {
        mExecutingActions = true;
        moveToState(nextState, false);
    } finally {
        mExecutingActions = false;
    }
    execPendingActions();
}
```

and then performResumeActivity in the ActivityThread throws an exception "Unable to resume activity " and next it goes down to ".IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing transactions"

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.proto.patryk.ou_gradecalculator/com.proto.patryk.ou_gradecalculator.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing transactions
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3581)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3621)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1638)
                  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
                  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
                  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
               Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing transactions
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.ensureExecReady(FragmentManager.java:2179)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:2211)
                  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:649)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:145)
                  at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.setAdapter(ViewPager.java:507)
                  at com.proto.patryk.ou_gradecalculator.MainActivity.onModulesRetrieved(MainActivity.java:414)
                  at com.proto.patryk.ou_gradecalculator.mainScreen.ModulesFragment.updateUI(ModulesFragment.java:437)
                  at com.proto.patryk.ou_gradecalculator.mainScreen.ModulesFragment.onResume(ModulesFragment.java:532)
                  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:2390)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1474)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1759)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1827)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3244)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchResume(FragmentManager.java:3212)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchResume(FragmentController.java:217)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onResumeFragments(FragmentActivity.java:509)
                  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPostResume(FragmentActivity.java:498)
                  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onPostResume(AppCompatActivity.java:171)
                  at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7141)
                  at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3556)
```

What I noticed is that although two fragments in the ViewPager are inflated, they are not updated if I delete one or more items from the top fragment (RecyclerView), which suggests that FragmentPagerAdapter does not replace those two fragments every time the onModulesRetrieved is called in the MainActivity.

The question is: how can I avoid the "FragmentManager is already executing transactions" error?
Someone already had a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40829361/3831895)
And an advice was to use below in fragment:

```
mPagerAdapter = new ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
mPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);
```

but my fragments have a different logic and are controlled by FragmentPagerAdapter.

UPDATE:

I replaced FragmentPagerAdapter with FragmentStatePagerAdapter to allow destroying entire fragment and recreating each time data has changed. However, the "FragmentManager is already executing transactions" exception is still present.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I fixed the bug above:

1. I changed FragmentStatePagerAdapter back to FragmentPagerAdapter
2. I added a new override method getItemPosition(@NonNull Object object) in the FragmentPagerAdapter. It returns POSITION_UNCHANGED if the position of the item has not changed, which is a default behaviour.

   ```
   @Override
   public int getItemPosition(Object frObj) {
       if(frObj instanceof CalcFragmentBottomA){
           ((CalcFragmentBottomA) frObj).updateUI(moduleList);
       }else if(frObj instanceof CalcFragmentBottomB){
           ((CalcFragmentBottomB) frObj).updateUI(moduleList);
       }
       return super.getItemPosition(frObj);
   }
   ```
3. Then I simply called viewPager.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged(); within the callback method from a top fragment to notify synchronously the ViewPagerObserver that the data has changed and the views should update.

   ```
   @Override
   public void onModulesRetrieved(@NotNull List<? extends Module> moduleList) {
      this.moduleList = (List<Module>) moduleList;
      viewPagerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
   }
   ```