# Android crashed after updating androidx biometric to 1.0.0-alpha04

Tags: android, kotlin, androidx, biometrics, android-biometric-prompt

Everything works fine with `'androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.0-alpha03'`, however when I build my project with the latest `'androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.0-alpha04'` and call `myBiometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo)` it throws this exception: `FragmentManager is already executing transactions`.

Here is the stacktrace:

```
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing transactions
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.ensureExecReady(FragmentManager.java:2207)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2267)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:814)
        at androidx.biometric.BiometricPrompt.authenticateInternal(BiometricPrompt.java:525)
        at androidx.biometric.BiometricPrompt.authenticate(BiometricPrompt.java:465)
        at com.my.app.ui.LoginFragment.handleTouchIdAuth(LoginFragment.kt:161)
        at com.my.app.ui.LoginFragment.onViewCreated(LoginFragment.kt:62)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1471)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2646)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2416)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2372)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2273)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3273)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3229)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2466)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1483)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1784)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1852)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3269)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3229)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:201)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:620)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1391)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:2937)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:180)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:165)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:142)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Does anyone know what happened and what to do? For now, I'll stick with version **1.0.0-alpha03**

Thank you!

Comment: Have u checked this [FragmentManager is already executing transactions. When is it safe to initialise pager after commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38722325/7666442)

Comment: Yea I did heh. It didn't help, and I don't think it applies in my case.

Comment: Have you looked at the [Release Notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/biometrics#1.0.0-alpha04) for biometrics 1.0.0-alpha04? They mention the changes made to the newer version. I'd suggest using stable release versions for any apps that you intend to release to others for use. Alpha versions tend to change rapidly and the same is with beta and rc versions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT: The issue seems to be resolved, see @olearyj234's comment/answer for the correct way to reolve the issue with beta01 and newer.

--

There seems to be an issue with alpha04, reverting to alpha03 fixes it.
Guess we'll have to wait for alpha05 before upgrading.

Just wish Google had waited until the biometrics library was out of alpha before deprecating the fingerprint library...

Comment: like seriously, did they even do a smoke test on this? Even invoking the simple use case of BiometricPrompt.authenticate produces this bug for me, its not like it's happening in some weird corner case. Makes me think they didn't even QA this. Alpha3 is full of embarrassing bugs too. Who ever is working on this should be fired.

Comment: beta-01 still seems to have the same problem.

Comment: beta01 fixed the issue with a minor change to code, see my answer

Comment: @olearyj234 you are right, I can confirm that the issue is fixed by using the second constructor introduced in beta01

Answer (score 8):

The problem is fixed in `androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.0-beta01` by providing a second constructor. Until this release, i solved the issue by reverting to `alpha03` but there's an actual solution available now.

You can find the `beta01` release notes [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/biometric#1.0.0-beta01)

> We’ve introduced a second constructor for BiometricPrompt that allows
>   it to be hosted in a Fragment (as opposed to the existing constructor,
>   which requires a FragmentActivity).

You can find the new `BiometricPrompt` constructor documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/biometric/BiometricPrompt.html#BiometricPrompt(androidx.fragment.app.Fragment,%20java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20androidx.biometric.BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback))

```
BiometricPrompt(Fragment fragment, Executor executor, BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback callback)
```

**To fix, please follow the simple steps:**

1. Change your build.gradle to use biometric version `1.0.0-beta01`
2. Use the new constructor. In short, change the first argument to your fragment instead of the activity. See my code change below:

   ```
   val biometricPrompt = BiometricPrompt(activity!!, executor, callback)
   // Change the above line to the below line
   val biometricPrompt = BiometricPrompt(this, executor, callback)
   ```

Comment: I am using androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.0-beta02 and the above constructor.

I haven't found this issue while testing, yet i see many crashes on playstore including devies like Pixel3 for this one.

should i revert back to androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.0-beta01 ?

Comment: I have a pixel 3, I didn't experience an issue. There's a RC out now so give that a try. androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.0-rc01

Answer (score 1):

The problem still exists in latest version `androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.0-beta01`.

To fix it is to display biometricPrompt from handler:

```
    val promptInfo = BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
            .setTitle(fragmentActivity.getString(title))
            .setNegativeButtonText(fragmentActivity.getString(negativeButtonText))
            .build()
    val biometricPrompt = BiometricPrompt(...)

    // display biometricPrompt from handler
    Handler().post {
        biometricPrompt.authenticate(promptInfo)
    }
```

Comment: please see my answer, this issue HAS been fixed in beta01