# FragmentManager is already executing transactions when Executing biometricPrompt?.authenticate(promptInfo) inside a Fragment

Tags: android, biometrics, android-biometric-prompt

If you create biometricPrompt and promptInfo in the activity, it works fine. But I can't manage to make it work inside a fragment.

This is inside of a fragment and it gets called inside OnViewCreated. You do the same inside an activity it works great, 1 solution would be to pass the biometricPrompt and PromptInfo from the activity and pass it inside the fragment.

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    tryToDisplayBiometricPrompt()
}


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
private fun tryToDisplayBiometricPrompt() {
    //Create a thread pool with a single thread
    biometricPrompt = BiometricPrompt(activity as FragmentActivity, Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(), object : BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback() {
        override fun onAuthenticationSucceeded(result: BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationResult) {
            super.onAuthenticationSucceeded(result)
            authenticationSuccessful()
        }

        override fun onAuthenticationError(errorCode: Int, errString: CharSequence) {
            super.onAuthenticationError(errorCode, errString)
            if (errorCode == BiometricConstants.ERROR_NEGATIVE_BUTTON || errorCode == BiometricConstants.ERROR_USER_CANCELED || errorCode == BiometricPrompt.ERROR_CANCELED) return
            authenticationlistener?.isBiometricAvailable = false
            authenticationlistener?.onAuthenticationFailed()
        }
    })

    promptInfo = BiometricPrompt.PromptInfo.Builder()
            .setTitle(getString(R.string.biometric_title))
            .setSubtitle(getString(R.string.biometric_subtitle))
            .setDescription(getString(R.string.biometric_description))
            .setNegativeButtonText(getString(R.string.cancel))
            .build()

    biometricPrompt?.authenticate(promptInfo)
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to use the Main Thread Executor instead of Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor() try to replace this with yourContext.getMainExecutor() to receive Callback Events in the UI Thread

Comment: I tried, but still doesn't work.

Comment: If i put it inside Handler().post {} it works perfectly.

Comment: so it look like it's related to the Thread where the Code is executed.. weird, weird also that it work fine in the Activity, i still suspect it's related to the Executor you pass as parameter

Comment: Issue filed: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/131980596

Please star it so it gets attention

Comment: Thank you ^^, let's hope they fix it :)

Answer (score 10):

Please see below or the same answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55683300/android-crashed-after-updating-androidx-biometric-to-1-0-0-alpha04/57792067#57792067)

The problem is fixed in `androidx.biometric:biometric:1.0.0-beta01` by providing a second constructor. Until this release, i solved the issue by reverting to `alpha03` but there's an actual solution available now.

You can find the `beta01` release notes [here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/biometric#1.0.0-beta01)

> We’ve introduced a second constructor for BiometricPrompt that allows
> it to be hosted in a Fragment (as opposed to the existing constructor,
> which requires a FragmentActivity).

You can find the new `BiometricPrompt` constructor documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/biometric/BiometricPrompt.html#BiometricPrompt(androidx.fragment.app.Fragment,%20java.util.concurrent.Executor,%20androidx.biometric.BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback))

```
BiometricPrompt(Fragment fragment, Executor executor, BiometricPrompt.AuthenticationCallback callback)
```

**To fix, please follow the simple steps:**

1. Change your build.gradle to use biometric version `1.0.0-beta01` or greater
2. Use the new constructor. In short, change the first argument to your fragment instead of the activity. See my code change below:

   ```
   val biometricPrompt = BiometricPrompt(activity!!, executor, callback)
   // Change the above line to the below line
   val biometricPrompt = BiometricPrompt(this, executor, callback)
   ```