# App crashes when pressing back button while on viewpager

Tags: android, kotlin, fragmentmanager, android-viewpager2

App seems to crash when I press the virtual back button on android.

Viewpager2 setup in fragment:

```
val viewPager = view.findViewById<ViewPager2>(R.id.pager)
val tabLayout = view.findViewById<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>(R.id.polls_tabs)
val adapter = PollOverviewTabAdapter(parentFragmentManager , lifecycle)
viewPager?.adapter = adapter
```

PollOverviewTabAdapter:

```
private const val NUM_TABS = 2

class PollOverviewTabAdapter(fragmentManager: FragmentManager, lifecycle: Lifecycle) :
    FragmentStateAdapter(fragmentManager, lifecycle) {

    override fun getItemCount() = NUM_TABS

    override fun createFragment(position: Int): Fragment {
        when (position) {
            0 -> return support_poll_overview_chart()
            1 -> return support_poll_overview_response_list()
        }
        return no_items()
    }
}
```

Crash Log:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: FragmentManager is already executing transactions
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.ensureExecReady(FragmentManager.java:1931)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1967)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNow(BackStackRecord.java:305)
        at androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter$FragmentMaxLifecycleEnforcer.updateFragmentMaxLifecycle(FragmentStateAdapter.java:726)
        at androidx.viewpager2.adapter.FragmentStateAdapter$FragmentMaxLifecycleEnforcer$3.onStateChanged(FragmentStateAdapter.java:657)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:354)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.forwardPass(LifecycleRegistry.java:265)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.sync(LifecycleRegistry.java:307)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.moveToState(LifecycleRegistry.java:148)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:134)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:3026)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.start(FragmentStateManager.java:589)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:300)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2180)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2106)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager$5.run(FragmentManager.java:524)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:236)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7876)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:656)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:967)
```

Tried:

- Using fragmentManager
- Using childFragmentManager
- Using parentFragmentManager

Comment: this link may help you > https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38722325/fragmentmanager-is-already-executing-transactions-when-is-it-safe-to-initialise

Comment: Thanks, found the reason, while I was using childFragmentManager in this fragment the parent fragment was using a regular fragmentManager